# JavaFX custom dialog has references after removing froom scene

Tags: java, javafx, profiling, visualvm

I have a custom dialog that is added to the scene and then removed again. Doing profiling with VisualVM, I noticed that even after a GC run the instance of this dialog is still retained.

I know that this means that there must be a reference to that object somewhere so I had a look at the references:

[image]

As seen in the image there are a lot of references from `this$` which means inner classes, in this case they are bindings or `ChangeListener`s. The change listener can be replaced with `WeakChangeListener`. I'm not quite sure how I should handle the Bindings however.

Furthermore there are some references that do not make much sense at first glance:

- `bean` of type `SimpleStringProperty` or `SimpleObjectProperty`
- `oldParent` and `value` of type `Node$1`

So here are the concrete questions:
How to get around these strong references, so the object can actually be garbage collected? Would the use of lambda expressions instead of anonymous inner classes have any effect in this respect? How to figure out where the object is references by `bean`, `oldParent` and `value`.

**EDIT1:**
The `bean` references of type `SimpleStringProperty` are used in the super class and therefore should not cause an issue here, I guess. One `SimpleObjectProperty` `bean` reference comes from a utility method that provides an EventHandler. How would I resolve that, is there something similar for `EventHandler` as for `ChangeListener`s?

**EDIT2:**
I tried to come up with a simple application to reproduce the same thing. I could manage it and saw that I have basically the same fields listed in the heap dump, but then noticed that I have retained a reference to the component that is removed from the scene in my application. Once I let go of that reference it was cleaned up. The only noticeable difference is in my small example there is no reference in an Object array.

**EDIT3:**
I did some digging and found two places in the code that when commented out or not used, will not cause the object become eligible for garbage collection. The first one is this `ChangeListener`:

```
sailorState.numberOfSailorsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue,
            Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    int inTavern = newValue.intValue()-sailorsAdditionalOnShip.get();
    if (inTavern < 0) {
        sailorsAdditionalOnShip.set(Math.max(sailorsAdditionalOnShip.get() + inTavern, 0));
        inTavern = 0;
    }
    sailorsInTavern.set(inTavern);
    }
});
```

The second one is a bit more complex. The component is a Dialog that has a close button. On pressing that one the dialog closes. This is the code of the button, I do not think that with this part is the problem, but for completeness sake:

```
public class OpenPatricianButton extends Control {

    protected final StringProperty text;
    protected final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Font> currentFont;
    protected final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<MouseEvent>> onAction;

    public OpenPatricianButton(String text,
            final Font font) {
        super();
        this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "text", text);
        this.currentFont = new ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase<Font>() {

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "currentFont";
            }

            @Override
            public Font get() {
                return font;
            }
        };
        this.onAction = new SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<MouseEvent>>(this, "onAction");
        this.getStyleClass().add(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
        URL cssURL = getClass().getResource("/ch/sahits/game/javafx/control/"+getClass().getSimpleName()+".css");
        return cssURL.toExternalForm();
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text.get();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text.set(text);
    }

    public Font getFont() {
        return currentFont.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<EventHandler<MouseEvent>> onActionProperty() {
        return onAction;
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getOnAction() {
        return onAction.get();
    }

    public void setOnAction(EventHandler<MouseEvent> onAction) {
        this.onAction.set(onAction);
    }

}

public class OpenPatricianSmallWaxButton extends OpenPatricianButton {

    public OpenPatricianSmallWaxButton(String text,
            final Font font) {
        super(text, font);
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new OpenPatricianSmallWaxButtonSkin(this);
    }

    public OpenPatricianSmallWaxButton(String text) {
        this(text, Font.getDefault());
    }
}

public class OpenPatricianSmallWaxButtonSkin extends SkinBase<OpenPatricianSmallWaxButton> {

    public OpenPatricianSmallWaxButtonSkin(final OpenPatricianSmallWaxButton button) {
        super(button);

        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sealingWaxFlattend.png");
        Image img = new Image(is);
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);

        final Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(button.textProperty());
        label.getStyleClass().add("OpenPatricianSmallWaxButtonLabeled");
        label.setFont(button.getFont());
        label.onMouseClickedProperty().bind(button.onActionProperty());
        label.textProperty().bind(button.textProperty());
        imageView.onMouseReleasedProperty().bind(button.onActionProperty());

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(imageView, label);
        Group group = new Group(stack);

        group.setManaged(false);

        button.setPrefHeight(img.getHeight());
        button.setPrefWidth(img.getWidth());

        getChildren().add(group);
    }
}
```

And here is the code fragment where the button is instantiated:

```
closeButton = new OpenPatricianSmallWaxButton("X", font);
closeButton.setLayoutX(WIDTH - CLOSE_BUTTON_WIDTH - CLOSE_BUTTON_PADDING);
closeButton.setLayoutY(CLOSE_BTN_Y_POS);
closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
      executeOnCloseButtonClicked();
  }
});
closeButton.getStyleClass().add("buttonLabel");
getContent().add(closeButton);
```

The call to remove the button is done through Guava `AsyncEventBus`. Therefore the code is a bit length. It starts in the Application thread and then gets posted to the event bus thread which then eventually has to call `Platform.runLater`:

```
protected void executeOnCloseButtonClicked() {
    ViewChangeEvent event = new ViewChangeEvent(MainGameView.class, EViewChangeEvent.CLOSE_DIALOG);
    clientEventBus.post(event);
}
public void handleViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getAddresse().equals(MainGameView.class)) {
    if (event.getEventNotice() instanceof DialogTemplate) {
          setNewDialog((DialogTemplate) event.getEventNotice());
    } else {
        sceneEventHandlerFactory.getSceneEventHandler().handleEvent(event.getEventNotice());
    }
    }
}

public void handleEvent(Object eventNotice) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(dialogContoller, "Dialog controller must be initialized first");
    if (eventNotice == EViewChangeEvent.CLOSE_DIALOG) {
        dialogContoller.closeDialog();
    }
    ....

public void closeDialog() {
    if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        closeDialogUnwrapped();
    } else {
        Platform.runLater(() -> closeDialogUnwrapped());
    }
}

private void closeDialogUnwrapped() {
    if (dialog != null) {
        new Exception("Close dialog").printStackTrace();
        getChildren().remove(dialog);
        dialog = null;
        dialogScope.closeScope();
    }
}
```

The really peculiar thing is that the dialog can be cleaned up by the GC (provided the first issue with the `ChangeListener` is commented out) when I call `closeDialog` from a timer. In other words this behaviour does only happen if I close the dialog with a mouse click.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE], with a corresponding screenshot from the profiling when running it? It's quite hard to speculate on where the references are being retained without seeing any code...

Comment: I did some more digging and found two places in the code that prevent the object from being garbage collected. I added these segments to the post.